# How to modify this regular expression to affect only "/..."?

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, http

I use the following regular expression to 'prepend' the base address of the website to all (href|src) on the document:

for example: `http://www.mywebsite.com/basedir/`

```
$output = preg_replace( "/(href|src){1}=(\'|\")*[\/]{1}(.*)(\'|\")*/ismU", "$1=$2{$baseaddress}$3$4", $output );
```

It works fine and I get results like this:

`src="/windows/file.png"` --->

```
src="http://www.mywebsite.com/basedir/windows/file.png"
```

But I have a problem, when src is `src="//fonts.googleapis.com/fonts.css"` 
I get: `http://www.mywebsite.com/basedir//fonts.googleapis.com/fonts.css`

How can I modify this regex to affect only `href|src` that begins with only one (1) `'/` ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: `[\/]{1}`
To: `\/(?!\/)`

This will ensure that the character after that first slash is not itself a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = preg_replace( "/(href|src){1}=(\'|\")*[\/]{1}([^\/]*)(\'|\")*/ismU", "$1=$2{$baseaddress}$3$4", $output );
```

Using `[^/]` instead of `.*`